# Passing screenProps to a tab navigator

Tags: react-native

**Background**

I have a root component that controls the views of 2 components. I am conditionally rendering these components.

I am passing `screenProps` to these 2 components so I can expose a `function` from the root components.

When component 1 is rendered it takes the `screenProps` perfectly. But component 2 is actually controlled by a `tabNavigator`. So when it is loaded, it is the default component in the `tabNavigator` which ends up being `Login`.

I want to pass the `screenProps` down multiple components or in other words give access to a function from root in the `Login` component, which is a component that is loaded through the `TabNavigator`.

**Example**

```
<Secure screenProps={{ login: () => this.setState:({ secure: false }) }} />
<Public screenProps={{ login: () => this.setState:({ secure: true }) }} />

Secure takes the component fine. But the  screenProps is called inside of the actual Secure component. The Public component has a TabNavigator. So when I pass screenProps to Public the components loaded via the TabNavigator do not have access to the screen props.
```

**Question**

How do I pass `screenProps` to the children of `Public` which are loaded through a `TabNavigator`?

**Code**

Component that calls the `TabNavigator`

```
const Public = props => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* <Header
            headerStyle={StyleSheet.flatten(styles.headerColor)}
            headerTitle="wunO"
        /> */}
        <BottomTabNav /* screenProps past here! */ />
    </View>
);
```

`LoginComponent` which is loaded when tab is clicked from the `PublicComponent`.

```
 async getToken() {
      try {
          const tokenKey = 'WUNO-TOKEN';
          const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(tokenKey, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                  throw err;
              }
              this.props.screenProps.login();
          });
          return token;
      } catch (e) {
          throw e;
      }
```

}

So all together,

**Main Component**

```
<Public screenProps={{ login: () => this.setState({ secure: true }) }} />
```

**Public Component**

```
<BottomTabNav screenProps={props.screenProps.login} />
```

**Login Component**

```
this.props.screenProps.login();
```

This throws the error,

> Cannot read property 'login of undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is actually right. In your Login Component `screenProps` doesn't have a login property because you pass the value of login property in Public Component.

You can either change Public component like below,

```
<BottomTabNav screenProps={{ login: props.screenProps.login}} />
```

or you can change execution in Login Component like below,

```
this.props.screenProps();
```

Comment: These both do not work. I have read some places that people have been unable to pass screen props 2 components down like this. Are you sure this should work? I am wondering now if this just does not work at the end of the day.

Comment: Your error is related to not using proper property. If you elaborate _not work_ part I might help. If you are still having any errors please update your question with the last version of what you tried and with the new error message